# .gitignore doesn't work in windows terminal

Tags: git

So i made **logs** file in this directory :

[image]

And then used `echo logs/ > .gitignore`

After that i used `code .gitignore` to ignore **logs/** in my **.gitignore** and i'm doing this on new **Windows Terminal** but i get this when i go to see the status :

[image]

Here is the actual content on my **.gitignore** :

[image]

But when i do all of this on **Git Bash** i get the expected result and if i go to windows terminal after that it somehow got applied to it and now **logs/** got ignored.

I don't know what is wrong with my windows terminal so i would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please post **the actual contents** of your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: did you try to gitignore `logs` without a forward slash?

Comment: @Mehdi yes i tried everything

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid "i tried everything", I'm pretty sure you did not stand in a tomato-sauce rain wearing a tuxedo asking Bululu for a divine intervention. Describe _what_ you did. Also, please kindly do not post images of text you can easily copy and paste

Comment: Have you `git add .gitIgnore`-ed the file?

Comment: Have you already tracked the logs\ folder in a previous commit? If so, this approach won't work.

Comment: @Dai I've edited my post with content you wanted

Comment: Maybe use `logs*` instead of `logs/`

Comment: @DaemonPainter no i didn't tracked the file if you see the images you would find out

Comment: @jessehouwing No, i did not

Comment: @apalomer That didn't work

Comment: Do that, once the ignore file is tracked it should become active.

Comment: @jessehouwing I want to ignore it as an untracked file, adding it to Index is not the what i'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

You mention that this does seem to work correctly when using `bash` as your shell, but not when using some other command-line-interpreter (whatever comes up in "my windows terminal", presumably).  Some Windows users have experienced that their command line interpreter writes files using a Windows UTF-16-LE encoding, rather than UTF-8.  Git cannot read UTF-16-LE `.gitignore` file contents as it does not know how to decode UTF-16-LE here.  So that's the most likely cause, as `bash` will not try to re-encode everything intu UTF-16-LE.

Answer (score 0):

@torek Thank you, it had something to do with `utf-8.

I added a few lines in my powershell profile notepad :

`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`

`$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'`

`$PSDefaultParameterValues['Get-Content:Encoding'] = 'utf8'`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4REM.png)

Then i checked the box for `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support` :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNGZd.png)

After rebooting the computer it worked and started to ignore `logs/` :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvDU1.png)

I'm grateful for your help.